# Can't find list of users in Strapi cron job

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, strapi

I want to create a Strapi cron job but I have a problem when I try to get the list of users.

That's how looks my server.js file:

```
const cronTasks = require("./cron-tasks");

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
  port: env.int('PORT', 1337),
  app: {
   keys: env.array('APP_KEYS'),
  },
cron: {
  enabled: true,
  tasks: cronTasks,
 },
});
```

And that's how looks my cron-tasks.js file:

```
module.exports = {
'*/5 * * * * *': async ({strapi}) => {
    try {
        const users = await strapi.service("plugin::users-permissions.user").find();
        console.log(users);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
},
```

};

And my error:

```
strapi.service(...).find is not a function
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked with await strapi.entityService.findMany('plugin::users-permissions.user');

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with `strapi.db.query('plugin::users-permissions.user').find()`?